# Trying to get property of non-object error JSON

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the location of Instagram pictures from my account. The API is giving me all sorts of information about my account and pictures, but when I try to get the location of my pictures it says:

> Trying to get property of non-object in ....

My code looks like this:

```
foreach($phplijst->data as $data){
    echo "<img src=" . $data->images->low_resolution->url . " />";
    echo "<p>" . $data->location->longitude . "</p>";
}
```

The first "echo" gives me all the images from my account. The second "echo" is supposed to give me the longitude of all the images on my account. Instead it gives me that error message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It means that `$data->location` isn't an object.
You should check your object structure with `var_dump($data)` and verify it has the layout you expect.

Comment: I did the var_dump thing and it said this:
["location"]=> NULL
Does this mean that my image just doesn't have any location attached to it?

Comment: Ok, good.  That explains why you're getting an error.  It's up to you to either 1) fix your data or 2) work around `location` being null.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys! I've fixed it.
I forgot to add a location to my images so that's why I didn't get a location :)
Thanks for the help anyway!